# Unable to Install Swagger Plugin <PluginManagerAction.ThisPlugin.NotAvailable> (ReadyAPi3.8.1)

Tags: plugins, swagger, ready-api

Am trying to install Swagger Plugin in <ReadyApi3.8.1> using option "Install from file" by getting plugin from https://github.com/smartbear/readyapi-swagger-plugin mentioned in https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/integrations/swagger.html but upon browse alert appear that ***"PluginManagerAction.ThisPlugin.NotAvailable"***.

Can anyone help me with this as I have to use Swagger Plugin. Using SwaggerHub is not an option in my case.
***Note: Error screenshot is attached.***
[image]

Comment: In ReadyAPI 3.8.1 this plugin is bundled, you don't have to install anything. The doc you linked to mentions that extra installation is only needed in ReadyAPI v. 2.1 and earlier.

Comment: SwggeerHub is bundled in ReadyAPi 3.8.1 but i want to install Swagger Plugin not SwaggerHub...might b both are same but it seems they are not bcoz for SwaggerHub i have deploy separate instance for it.

Comment: Both are bundled. I believe the Swagger plugin is now part of the core product, that's why it doesn't show as a plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need that plugin. OpenAPI/Swagger support (i.e. that plugin's functionality) has been core part of ReadyAPI [since v. 2.2](https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/general-info/version-history/features-added-to-ver-2-2.html):

> We have also ported support for earlier Swagger versions to the product (Swagger 1.x and 2.0). **So, the ReadyAPI Swagger plugin is not needed anymore.**